# Why does typescript not recognise my variable is an array after checking function?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a simple checking function for array length:

```
export const hasLength = (arr?: unknown[]) => {
  const isArray = Array.isArray(arr);
  return isArray && arr.length !== 0;
};
```

I'd expect typescript to recognise that the variable is an array with length after checking through the function but it doesn't. Is this expected behaviour and why if so?

```
{hasLength(auction.bids) && (
  <div>
    {[...auction.bids].reverse().map((bid) => null);
  </div>
)}
```

Error is `Type 'string[] | undefined' is not an array type or does not have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts`

[image: TS Array type]

Comment: Because `hasLength` isn't a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), it just returns a regular `boolean`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for the narrowing to "carry over" into the scope it was called:

```
export const hasLength = (arr: unknown[] | undefined): arr is unknown[] => {
  const isArray = Array.isArray(arr);
  return isArray && arr.length !== 0;
};
```

---

If you really need it to be an array of at least length 1, then you can use `[T, ...T[]]` with a generic:

```
export const hasLength = <T>(arr: T[] | undefined): arr is [T, ...T[]] => {
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVkPqm)